# Resume the Activity instead of Starting if already exists in back stack

Tags: android, back-stack

I have an `Activity_1` after a lot of steps, say

`Activity_2` **>** `Activity_3` .... in some `Activity_n` I change some data related to `Activity_1` and call it using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_n.this, Activity_1.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

To refresh the content. But later I can go all the way back to `Activity_1` where I started, which has old data.

Instead I want the initial `Activity_1`' s `onResume()` to be called, using the above code. Or appropriate **Flag**

**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**

> consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls
>   startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of
>   activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given
>   Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

That' what the docs say, but not what I am getting.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can add this two lines and try

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Write this in your manifest file inside Activity

```
<activity
     android:name=".SettingsActivity"
     android:launchMode="singleInstance"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

"singleTask" and "singleInstance" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task.

You can use SingleTask or SingleInstance

"singleTask"    -   The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

"singleInstance"    -   Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task.

Refer this link  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: But this is a **Fragment** I am using. Till now I was using `onResume()` of the **Fragment**. Which doesn't contain anything Like `onNewIntent()`.But isn't there a way to clear the whole back stack and call a new **Activity**

Comment: See I have added two lines you can try that way

Comment: singleInstance and singleTask are "not appropriate for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications."
I recommend to find another solution because these are more for use with widgets etc.

Comment: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` was enough for me

Answer (score 22):

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Visit : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Comment: This is a much better version of launchmode="SingleInstance". I've been looking for this Flag.

Comment: This works fine for me. In my case, I need to open an activity from the background and avoid launching the activity twice. I need this behavior only in this one case.

Answer (score 8):

Resume `Activity` from backstack if exists or create a new one if not

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

add this line to your app's AndroidManifest.xml and start the activity with a normal `Intent`.